# Type 'ViewController' has no member 'btnPressed'

Tags: ios, swift

I try to add observers to my *Swift 3* application but when I want to set the method that should be called from the observer I get the following error:

> Type 'ViewController' has no member 'btnShowMorePressed'

The function `btnShowMorePressed` is declared directly under the `addOberservers` function.

```
func addObservers(){

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.btnShowMorePressed(_:)), name: btn1TappedDone, object: nil)
}

func btnShowMorePressed(sender: NSNotification){
    print("btnShowMorePressed was called.")
}
```

I tried to clean the project (Product -> Clean) but is still gives me the error. What am I doing wrong with adding an observer?

Answer (score 4):

It should be:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.btnShowMorePressed), name: btn1TappedDone, object: nil)
```

And yes, it does recognize the right `sender` for the `btnShowMorePressed(sender: NSNotification)` method.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.btnShowMorePressed(sender:)), name: btn1TappedDone, object: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one `btnShowMorePressed(sender: NSNotification)` method in your code then it is fine to use:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(btnShowMorePressed), name: btn1TappedDone, object: nil)
```

But if you have same method name but with different parameters, then should use in this way:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(btnShowMorePressed(sender:)), name: btn1TappedDone, object: nil)
```

For an instance in following case you cannot use first way, because you get "`Ambiguous use of 'btnShowMorePressed'`" error:

```
func btnShowMorePressed(sender: NSNotification){
    print("btnShowMorePressed was called.")
}
func btnShowMorePressed(parameter: String){
    print("btnShowMorePressed was called.")
}
```

I always use second way because it is more clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're quite confused about how to pass selectors to a method.

There is a simple rule to remember,

> When you're refering to a method in the same class, just write `#selector(`, followed by the name of the method, and a `)`.

It is that simple!

You would attach the class name only when you want to refer to a method outside of the class.

So here, it would be `#selector(btnShowMorePressed)`

Full code:

```
func addObservers(){

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(btnShowMorePressed), name: btn1TappedDone, object: nil)
}

func btnShowMorePressed(sender: NSNotification){
    print("btnShowMorePressed was called.")
}
```